# Who are the top thought leaders in the project management space? Why?

Tags: untagged

Please include links to their blogs, books, or articles, if possible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Project Management Stack Exchange, the Q&A Site for Project Managers. The best questions to ask here are the ones that are about a specific problem that you face. In general, we try to avoid polling questions or questions that ask for lists, etc. However, I think that if you edit your question and provide more specific details, your question may be salvageable. Thanks again and welcome to our site!

Answer (score 0):

Ones I know and like a lot:

[John Seddon, "Freedom from Command and Control"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1563273276)

[Jurgen Appelo, "Management 3.0"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321712471)

They might not be "top", but they're worth reading. Jurgen in particular introduces a lot of other concepts which are related to his style, so if you're looking to find out what you don't know you don't know, read his first.

Answer (score 0):

*Rework* from the 37 Signals guys gives you a really different spin on Project Management.

[http://www.amazon.com/Rework-Jason-Fried/dp/0307463745/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1311506689&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307463745)